# Why PHP Session is not changing after update?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

Case:
The first problem is I don't want user to go back from browser navigation. So when they click back from browser navigation they will directly go to a specific controller

So there is A and B controller

In A controller
I set the session of Status become false `($this->session->set_userdata("status",false)`. When they continue to B controller  I set the status become true `($this->session->set_userdata("status",true)`. I print the session status and it's showing true

When user click back , In the index function of A controller . I read session status but it's still showing false. My expectation is it's showing true since i've update it in B controller.

Anyone know how to solve this session case then?

Even when i reload the A controller, the session status still false

**EDIT**

Try to reload multiple times in a controller

```
 print_r("this is session1");
 print_r($this->session->userdata("abcde"));
 print_r("this is session2");

        $data = array(
            'title' => 'add sess'
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata("abcde",$data);
        print_r($this->session->userdata("abcde"));
```

the output is

this is session1 this is session2 Array(    [title] => add sess)

isn't the expected output is : this is session1 Array(    [title] => add sess) this is session2 Array(    [title] => add sess)

Comment: *In A controller I set the session of Status become false `($this->session->set_userdata("status",false)` ... Even when i reload the A controller, the session status still false* ... if you're doing that in the "A Controller" then, yes, it's going to be false when you crank it up right?

Comment: setting status session in A controller at the first time  is not in index, it's set when user trigger a button that direct to b controller @CD001

Comment: _"I read session status but it's still showing false."_ - and you're sure you did not simply get fooled by your browser cache there? If you reload that page you are now on, the session data stays as is?

Comment: @CBroe I've add some info in thread above

Comment: Did you verify the session ID stays the same between requests?

Comment: Try print_r(session_id()); Every time i refresh the page it's change.  But i have 3 environtments  development, staging, and production. The thing is it's work both staging and development. Not working in production